# Deterministic CSL = semi Deterministic CSL

Tags: turing-machines, context-sensitive

How can it be proven that a
deterministic CSL = semi-deterministic CSL?

Does that imply that a CSL = semi CSL?

Would I need to build a Turing machine, since a language accepted by a Turing machine is considered semi CSL?

Comment: What are deterministic CSL and semi-deterministic CSL?

Comment: Presumably every deterministic CSL is semi-deterministic CSL by definition, so in order to prove that the classes coincide, you will need to show that every semi-deterministic CSL is in fact deterministic CSL.

Comment: What’s the most appropriate way to show that ?